# $PATH after removing Anaconda3

Tags: bash, path, uninstallation

My .bashrc file has these lines in the end:

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/tsakire/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
conda activate
conda activate
. /home/tsakire/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

After removing Anaconda3 with rm -rf,
I would like to know what to write replacing these 5 lines of my .bashrc file.

I don't know which is the proper path, since my /etc/environment file writes:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

while my .profile has:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Should I also delete the last 3 lines?
Should I change the .profile path, as well, to what /etc/environment says?

Comment: When anaconda was installed it should have generated a .bash_profile-anaconda3.bak file in your home directory which will contain your previous path. Do you have one of these files or an equivalent for the .bashrc file?

Comment: I found it, but it doesn't contain a pathname. It's the same as .bashrc, only without these 5 added lines in the end. Anyway, I falsely believed that .bashrc MUST contain the path, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove those last five lines which are clearly marked as added by and for Anaconda. They merely add stuff to the default `PATH` which of course no longer should be added.

The system sets up a sensible default path which generally you should not override completely. It's fine to add stuff like

```
PATH=new_stuff:$PATH
```

where `$PATH` recalls the previous value of the variable, like both the Anaconda installer and your own additions did. (Many instructions also `export` the variable but this is usually redundant.)

Comment: After some search on how paths work [https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77898], I understood that I falsely believed that .bashrc file MUST contain the path. I just deleted these added-by-anaconda  lines and everything seems fine.